# Questions for migrating differential data from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

1. Magento 1.9 runs on a production server.
2. Magento 2.2 runs on a test environment server.
3. I have finished setting up the migration tool. No errors.
4. We built a database on the test environment server based on the Magento 1.9 dump file.
5. The first migration is over. No errors.

Currently, data is not added, deleted or updated from the administrator screen.

You are ready to migrate the incremental data.

But I have a question.

During the initial migration, tables with names starting with m2_* were created in the Magento 1.9 database.

Dumping the Magento 1.9 database in the production environment and building it on the validation environment server will delete the m2 _ * tables.

How can I migrate incremental data?

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible on test server.

Magento1 databse should be on production server for incremental migration.

I have tried with copying m2_cl_* tables on production and then doing incremental migration but it will not work